# execute only if the children are different in componentDidUpdate

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, children, react-props

I need to compare the children of prevProps and the current props and only execute the code if they're different in componentDidUpdate method.

How could I compare the children when they're arrays of objects?

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if(!_.isEqual(prevProps.children, this.props.children)) {
   console.log('not equal');
   // execute some code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use regular equality operator like that:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.children !== this.props.children) {
        console.log('not equal');
    }
}
```

This is what react documentation says. However note that, this will only check if the array is different. It will not detect if object inside an array was changed, but because of how react works it is acceptable.

Comment: I guess it will not compare nested objects?

Comment: Sure, but if children changes react will assign new children array to component props.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `===` to compare children but if you need to perform a expensive calculations or cause re rendering a lot when props.children are not the same you can memoize the children in the parent so you won't do that unless children actually really changed:

```js
function App() {
  const [children, setChildren] = React.useState([
    { id: 0, name: 'one' },
    { id: 1, name: 'two' },
  ]);
  const [, setUnRelated] = React.useState({});
  const addChild = () =>
    setChildren(children =>
      children.concat({
        id: children.length,
        name: 'new child',
      })
    );
  const Children = React.useMemo(
    () => children.map(c => <Child key={c.id} {...c} />),
    [children]
  );
  console.log('parent rendering');
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={addChild}>Add child</button>
      <button onClick={() => setUnRelated({})}>
        Unrelated change
      </button>
      <ChildList>{Children}</ChildList>
    </div>
  );
}
class ChildList extends React.PureComponent {
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.children !== this.props.children) {
      console.log('Children in child list not equal');
    }
  }
  render() {
    return this.props.children;
  }
}

const Child = React.memo(function Child({ id, name }) {
  const rendered = React.useRef(0);
  rendered.current++;
  return (
    <div>
      Rendered {rendered.current} times for: {name} id: {id}
    </div>
  );
});

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```